# Css When having 2 bg-image, how to have 1 to extend out of the grid

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple website using 960 grid with a responsive framework call 'skeleton', it is working fine but i am having one issue now, as my header banner is only 960px, there will be an awkward white spaces that will continue out of 960px on both side. To solve that i have slice out 1 pixel of the image and then i repeat it throughout the x axis.

Problem:
Since .container will restrict maintain everything within 960px, i can't put the page_home/section_header_bg.jpg to extend out of the 960px restriction. I tried to create it out of the .container div, but it will caused the 2 image to not merge together. I want them to be inline together.

It works very well if i'm not using the .container, but my header will not be responsive.

Issue: don't know how to get url(page_home/section_header_bg.jpg) to extend out of the 960px restriction while overlaying the main image with the bg fill up

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-image:
    url(page_home/section_header.jpg),
    url(page_home/section_header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: center, left;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wrapper for your header and use the container after the header(for the nav, etc):

```
.head-wrap{
    width:100%;
    background:yourbackground;
}

header{
    max-width:960px;
    yourstyles;
}
```

markup:

```
<div class="head-wrap">
    <header>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

This would be the cleanest solution. Otherwise you would have to put a div with position:absolute behind your header and put the background styles on this. Then, because you have a `min-height` property, you would need to rescale it with javascript everytime the browser window is being rescaled, because it won't scale the same way as your header would, as it has no content. Just to get the idea:

```
<div class="yourbackgrounddiv"></div>
<div class="container">
    <header>
    </header>
</div>

.yourbackgrounddiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    yourstyles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick with media query, I think that you need 1px image only in the case of desktop not with handheld devices. with this you can play further.

Just create a bg div on above the container with position:absolute.

That will work for you.

Thanks